# Property "xxx" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

this is part of js

```js
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      lineList: [],
    }
  },
  ...
  created(){
    await this.getLineList()
  }
  ...
  getLineList(){
    ...
    //use axios to get data
    this.lineList = res.data
    ...
  }
```

this is part of temlate

```html
       ...
       <el-form-item label="line">
          <el-select
            v-model="searchInfo.id"
            default-first-option
            placeholder="select line"
          >
            <el-option
              v-for="item in lineList"
              :key="item.id"
              :label="item.name"
              :value="item.id"
              :value-key="id"
            />
          </el-select>
        </el-form-item>
        ...
```

And console a lot of warning, like: Property "xxx" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
How to avoid warning?

Comment: Not sure if the code snippets omit some parts, but I can sea that `data()` does not return `searchInfo` which is used in the template in a `v-model`

Answer (score 0):

`created()`is a hook function but your custom methods should be declared in the "methods" property

```
...
methods: {
    getLineList(){
        ...
    }
}
```